# What's the way to change metadata parameters in ERC721/1155?

Tags: solidity

So imagine there are ERC-721 (or ERC-1155?) with metadata

One of parameters is Strength:

It slowly decrease on every transfer from 100 to 0

How can it be programmable without burning and minting token again and again with new metadata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a `mapping` that takes the token ID as the key, and the strength as the value.

Then you can expand your `mint` and `transfer` functions to set the correct value.

```
mapping (uint256 => uint8) tokenIdToStrength;

function mint() external {
    uint256 tokenId = // TODO the actual mint
    tokenIdToStrength[tokenId] = 100;
}

function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId) external {
    require(tokenIdToStrength[_tokenId] > 0, 'Strength is zero, cannot transfer anymore');
    tokenIdToStrength[_tokenId]--; // decrement by 1
    // TODO the actual transfer
}
```